# Pass a variable from python to shell script

Tags: python, bash, shell

I am running a shell script from inside a python script like this:

```
call(['bash', 'run.sh'])
```

And I want to pass `run.sh` a couple of variables from inside of the python script. It looks like I can just append variables, something like so:

```
call(['bash', 'run.sh', 'var1', 'var2'])
```

and then access them in my shell script with $1 and $2. But I can't get this to work.

Comment: What do you mean you cannot get it to work? What else are you getting ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables from python script to bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4257098/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `call(['bash', 'run.sh'])` is working without arguments, there is no reason why it shouldn't work when additional arguments are passed.

You need to substitute the *values* of the variables into the command line arguments, not just pass the *names* of the variables as strings as does this:

```
call(['bash', 'run.sh', 'var1', 'var2'])
```

Instead, do this:

```
var1 = '1'
var2 = '2'
call(['bash', 'run.sh', var1, var2])
```

Now this will work providing that `var1` and `var2` are strings. If not, you need to convert them to strings:

```
var1 = 1
var2 = 2
call(['bash', 'run.sh', str(var1), str(var2)])
```

Or you can use `shlex.split()`:

```
cmd = 'bash run.sh {} {}'.format(var1, var2)
call(shlex.split(cmd))
```

Answer (score 13):

There are two built-in python modules you can use for this. One is `os` and the other is `subprocess`. Even though it looks like you're using `subprocess`, I'll show both.

Here's the example bash script that I'm using for this.

**test.sh**

```
echo $1
echo $2
```

---

**Using subprocess**

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.call(['bash','test.sh','foo','bar'])
foo
bar
```

This should be working, can you show us the error or output that you're currently getting.

---

**Using os**

```
>>> import os
>>> os.system('bash test.sh foo bar')
foo
bar
0
```

Note the exit status that `os` prints after each call.

Answer (score 3):

use subprocess to call your shell script

subprocess.Popen(['run.sh %s %s' % (var1, var2)], shell = True).

Comment: This won't work as expected if `var1` contains whitespace or one of several other shell metacharacters. There is rarely a good reason to use the single-string argument to `Popen` in place of a list.

Answer (score -2):

```
import os
def run():
    os.system('C:\\scrips\\mybash.bat')
run()
```